# fscanf() only picking up first line of file

Tags: c, text-files, scanf

I have a tab delimited file that I am trying to convert to a tab delimited file. I am using C. I am getting stuck on trying to read the second line of the file. Now I just have an tens of thousand of lines repeating the first line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SELLERCODE  A2LQ9QFN82X636

int main ()
{
     typedef char* string;
     FILE* stream;
     FILE* output;
     string asin[200];
     string sku[15];
     string fnsku[15];
     int quality = 0;

     stream = fopen("c:\\out\\a.txt", "r");
     output = fopen("c:\\out\\output.txt", "w");

     if (stream == NULL)
     { 
         perror("open");
         return 0;
      }

     for(;;)
     {
       fscanf(stream, "%[^\t]\t%[^\t]", sku, fnsku);
       printf("%s\t%s\n",  sku, fnsku);
       fprintf(output, "%s\t%s\t%\t%s\t%s\t%i\n", sku, fnsku, asin, quality);
     }

}
```

Comment: "I have a tab delimited file that I am trying to convert to a tab delimited file"? Well then, it's your lucky day, there's nothing to do! :P could you post some code, so we can diagnose the problem?

Comment: Can you post your code? There is too little information here.

Comment: Huh? convert tab delimited to tab delimited? just write what you read ...

Comment: We'd need to see your failing code to be able to tell you what you're doing wrong -- as it stands, this isn't really a valid question.

Comment: @Santiago @Shea @pmg @Ernst I hit submit to early.

Comment: As written, you are declaring arrays of `char*` when you want arrays of `char`.  I don't see how that leads to the behavior you describe, but it isn't what you want.

Comment: @andrewdski I changed that to char[] but still same end results.

Comment: @Joe Tyman: "I have a tab delimited file" does the line end also with a tab? i mean these is only one line in the file (no `'\n'` characters) and only `'\t'` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prefer `fgets()` to read the input and parse the lines in your program, using, for example,  `sscanf()` or `strtok()`.

`fscanf` is notoriously difficult to use.
Your fscanf is not performing any conversions after the first line.
It reads characters up to a <kbd>TAB</kbd>, then ignores the <kbd>TAB</kbd>, and reads more characters up to the next <kbd>TAB</kbd>. On the 2nd time through the loop, there is no data for `sku`: the 1st character is a <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

Do **check the return value** though. It helps enormously.

```
chk = fscanf(stream, "%[^\t]\t%[^\t]", sku, fnsku);
/* 2 conversions: sku and fnsku */
if (chk != 2) {
    /* something went wrong */
}
```

Comment: fgets() is also quiet limiting. I have a few fields that I will be trying to read. I also plan to read an integer from this fscanf().

Comment: Saying it's "difficult to use" isn't helpful. Is it inappropriate for the desired task? If so, say why. If not, why shouldn't the OP learn how to use the appropriate function rather than throwing his hands up and using an easier, though potentially less adequate, function?

Answer (score 2):

You are reading with

```
   fscanf(stream, "%[^\t]\t%[^\t]", sku, fnsku);
```

After the first line is read, which should ends with a tab character (as in `"%[^\t]\t%[^\t]"`). The input buffer has the last tab character '\t' which is not read by the above function call. So in the next iteration it gets read at the beginning with your format string. But the `fcanf` in the next iteration immediately returns as it has encountered a tab character '\t' at the very beginning (`"%[^\t]"`) , so the buffers still have the last read in value. From now on each iteration tries to read the file with the `fscanf` but fails every time encountering a `'\t'` at the very beginning. So you do not progress reading the file, and the first read values from your program buffers are shown on and on.

You need to read out the last character which terminated the scanset matching. You can either use a `fgetc (stream)` after the `fscanf ()` call or use the following format string: `"%[^\t]\t%[^\t]%*c"` . The `%*c` is the assignment suppression syntax. This will make one character read from the input file but then discard it.

Also you should check what the `fscanf ()` returns. If it does not return 2 (the number of elements to read) then there is a problem which you should handle. This way you can ensure the correct number of elements were read at one call.

So either you can do:

```
 while (!feof (stream))
 {
   fscanf(stream, "%[^\t]\t%[^\t]", sku, fnsku);
   fgetc (stream);
   printf("%s\t%s\n",  sku, fnsku);
   fprintf(output, "%s\t%s\t%\t%s\t%s\t%i\n", sku, fnsku, asin, quality);
 }
```

Or you can do:

```
 while (!feof (stream))
 {
   fscanf(stream, "%[^\t]\t%[^\t]%*c", sku, fnsku);
   printf("%s\t%s\n",  sku, fnsku);
   fprintf(output, "%s\t%s\t%\t%s\t%s\t%i\n", sku, fnsku, asin, quality);
 }
```

But i will recommend to read it with `fgets ()` and then parse it inside your program with `strtok ()` or other means and ways.

**EDIT1:**

Note that if you have the original file terminated with a `'\n'` then after you read the lines as above an extra newline would be added into your buffers. If you still consider to directly read the fields with `fscanf ()` where each line has multiple fields seperated with `'\t'` and an entry is terminated with a `'\n'` then you should use the following format string: `"%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\n"`.

It is difficult to answer while we do not get the exact format of the file. Does the file contain only one single line with fields seperated with tabs? Or there are multiple lines, with each line having tab separated fields. If the later is true, best is to scan the whole line at once and then parse it internally.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is what is actually happening.  You are reading the first line, and from then on you aren't reading anything and just reusing those values.  You should check the return value of `fscanf` and exit the loop if it is less than two (which it will be after the first iteration).  Your `fscanf` line should look like this:

```
if( fscanf(stream, "%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\n", sku, fnsku) < 2 ) break;
```

The key is the newline at the end, which will eat the newline in the input.

There are some problems with your printf as well.  (Incorrect number of formatting strings.)  I'll leave that to you.